# Why is '362' > 378?

Tags: python, string, comparison, integer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Python compare string and int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int)

An intern was just asking me to help debug code that looked something like this:

```
widths = [image.width for image in images]
widths.append(374)
width = max(widths)
```

...when the first line should have been:

```
widths = [int(image.width) for image in images]
```

Thus, the code was choosing the string '364' rather than the integer 374.  How on earth does python compare a string and an integer?  I could understand comparing a single character (if python had a `char` datatype) to an integer, but I don't see any straightforward way to compare a string of characters to an integer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Python 2.x compares *every* built-in type to every other.  From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons):

> Objects of different types, except different numeric types and different string types, never compare equal; such objects are ordered consistently but arbitrarily (so that sorting a heterogeneous array yields a consistent result).

This "arbitrary order" in CPython is actually sorted by type name.

In Python 3.x, you will get a `TypeError` if you try to compare a string to an integer.

Answer (score 6):

When comparing values of incompatible types in python 2.x, the ordering will be arbitrary but consistent. This is to allow you to put values of different types in a sorted collection.

In CPython 2.x any string will always be higher than any integer, but as I said that's arbitrary. The actual ordering does not matter, it is just important that the ordering is consistent (i.e. you won't get a case where e.g. `x > y` and `y > z`, but `z > x`).

Comment: Thats for Python 2.X. Python 3.X does not compare items of different type by default.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#notin):

> Most other objects of built-in types
>   compare unequal unless they are the
>   same object; the choice whether one
>   object is considered smaller or larger
>   than another one is made arbitrarily
>   but consistently within one execution
>   of a program

Hope this is clear enough - like it has been said, it is arbitrary.

Comment: It seems to be arbitrary & consistent on one platform, but when I move the code to another platform the order can change.